# How to tell Jasmine setup/cleanup that all API requests have been made

Tags: jasmine, promise, generator

I am writing e2e tests (Protractor, Jasmine) 
I have to call an API multiple times to create, test, then delete resources (pagination test). 
I have used the request-promise + co approach (see gist below). 
However My Jasmine Test needs to know when all API requests are done. 
How/what do return to indicate API run is done?

```
//Jasmine test // AUT = app under test // HCS = some resouce to be created multiple times to test pagination
// defaultData has 11 defaultHCSID in array

describe ("Test: Create 11 HCSes to test pagination", function () {
    beforeAll(function (done) {
        AUT.api.defaultHCS.create(defaultData).then(()=> {
            done(); 
            //setTimeout(function () {done();}, AUT.API_TIMEOUT);
        });
    });
..
rest of the test.
..

//appointments defaultHCS Api.js
var co = require('co');
var _ = require('lodash');
var rp = require('request-promise');
var urlLogin ={url:"<URL>", body:"<body>" method: 'POST', headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, json: true}
var urlDefaultHCSSave ={url:"<URL>", body:"<body>" method: 'POST', headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, json: true}

exports.create = function (customTestData) {
    return co(function*() {
        var response, token, testData;
        testData = customTestData ||  defaultTestData;
        response = yield rp(urlLogin);
          urlDefaultHCSSave.headers["x-auth-token"] =   response.token;

        var size= _.size(testData.defaultHCSID);
        process.stdout.write("API DEFAULT HCS Create. Size: " + size + " ");
        var total = 0;
        testData.defaultHCSID.forEach(function (item,i){
            return co(function* () {
                response = yield rp(defaultHCSSave); //parsedBody
                total+=1;
                if (total === size){  process.stdout.write("All Done\n");      }
            }).catch(function (err) {console.error(err.stack); })
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is non-blocking, asynchronous, replacing it with 
'for..of` worked. (blocking, synchronous)